# What's the difference between より and よりも?

Tags: word-choice, words

I came across this sentence:

```
光{ひかり}は音{おと}よりも速{はや}く進{すす}む
```

And I don't understand the purpose of the word よりも. I have a feeling that より and よりも have basically the same meaning (more than) and も is used to emphasis it.

Is there any difference between より and よりも?

Thanks, Or

Comment: In this context よりも means "in comparison to"